# found a great code for leaflet map. I want when I hover on each html article to show to show the PIN location with a bouncing pin or a flashing icon

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have the following code:

I would like to display the pin on the map with a notification when I hover on the html article. The notification could be in the form of an attribute on top of the PIN location, a flashing icon from css, a bouncing pin. The notification should only be for the current html article when I hover on it.

when I hover on the article, I want to show its location on the map with either a bouncing pin or a flashing icon made from css pinpointing the location. Or quite simply, an attribute (title) of the current article displayed so that I can differentiate the pin location from the rest

```js
// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomControl: false, // zoom control off
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;
// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);
// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);
// reactivate zoom at the desired location
// [topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright]
L.control
  .zoom({
    position: "topright",
  })
  .addTo(map);
// holder for all articles
const articles = document.querySelectorAll("article");

const group = L.featureGroup();

articles.forEach((article) => {
  const coordinates = article.dataset.coordinates;
  const title = article.dataset.title;

  const marker = L.marker(JSON.parse(coordinates));

  marker.addTo(group).bindPopup(title);
});

group.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {
  padding: [50, 50], // adding padding to map
});
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji";
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.story-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.story {
  background: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.story article {
  padding: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="story-content flex">
  <div class="story">
    <article data-coordinates="[-17.981680132859903, -70.22885519135282]" data-title="title 1">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article data-coordinates="[-17.982343728408157, -70.22992798111379]" data-title="title 2">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article data-coordinates="[-18.00728838751793, -70.24685472283247]" data-title="title 3">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to open pin pop-up (title) when the occordingly article is hovered. I just add 2 lines of js to add event listeners :

```
  // open pop-up on article hover
  article.addEventListener('mouseover', () => marker.openPopup())
  article.addEventListener('mouseout', () => marker.closePopup())
```

Full code :

```js
// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomControl: false, // zoom control off
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;
// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);
// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);
// reactivate zoom at the desired location
// [topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright]
L.control
  .zoom({
    position: "topright",
  })
  .addTo(map);
// holder for all articles
const articles = document.querySelectorAll("article");

const group = L.featureGroup();

articles.forEach((article) => {
  const coordinates = article.dataset.coordinates;
  const title = article.dataset.title;

  const marker = L.marker(JSON.parse(coordinates));

  marker.addTo(group).bindPopup(title);

  // open pop-up on article hover
  article.addEventListener('mouseover', () => marker.openPopup())
  article.addEventListener('mouseout', () => marker.closePopup())
});

group.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds(), {
  padding: [50, 50], // adding padding to map
});
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji";
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.story-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.story {
  background: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.story article {
  padding: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="story-content flex">
  <div class="story">
    <article data-coordinates="[-17.981680132859903, -70.22885519135282]" data-title="title 1">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article data-coordinates="[-17.982343728408157, -70.22992798111379]" data-title="title 2">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
    <article data-coordinates="[-18.00728838751793, -70.24685472283247]" data-title="title 3">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel praesentium aliquam animi nisi eius sequi autem obcaecati hic itaque sint labore incidunt officiis, veritatis modi corporis unde. Eos, accusantium odit?
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Let me know what you think!

Comment: Absolutely grateful!! It works. 
i would like to add a cluster plugin for items that are located on the same gps address
i plan to use this plugin
  <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.5.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"
      integrity="sha384-89yDmbSkL9reFc77m10ZbqLaUMf1sp7FAJs2oAD/rczNnY7I+17yN9KML6tpYpCk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

//I'm not a javascript guy. How do I do that using 
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup()

Comment: I hope this helps : [https://jsfiddle.net/6xmb05qo/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/6xmb05qo/3/)
I use a lot of this [exemple from leaflet documentation](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)

Comment: Works like a charm. The only thing I modified was 
 const marker = L.marker(JSON.parse(coordinates), {title: title});

//you are real star!!!!

//Another query, If I want to auto expand a cluster when hovering on an article instead of clicking on the map to expand it, is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Or perhaps setView with a zoom of lets say 14  to center on the map when I hover on the list item. If you can modify the last code that would be great. many thanks
where

Comment: You can find a way of doing so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p0f7w8ck/50/).

Comment: To say that I'm thrilled is an understatement. You absolutely know your stuff. I have customized it and now pulling popup binding data via php from mysql databaase. THANK YOU very much for the help and support.